# Single DispatcherServlet with Multiple Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create some restful web services using Spring MVC 3.0.  I currently have an issue that only 1 of my 2 controllers will work at any given time.  As it turns out, whichever class comes first when sorted alphabetically will work properly.  The error I get is:

handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/polinq.xml', method 'GET', parameters map[[empty]]

I had a very simliar message earlier also, except instead of the map being empty it was something like map[v-->String(array)]

Regardless of the message though, currently the LocationCovgController works and the PolicyInquiryController doesn't.  If I change the change of the PolicyInquiryController to APolicyInquiryController, then it will start funcitoning properly and the LocationCovgController will stop working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Jeremy

The information provided below includes the skeleton of both controller classes and also the servlet config file that defines how spring should be setup.

### Controller 1

```
package org.example;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/polinq.*")
public class PolicyInquiryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/polinq.*?comClientId={comClientId}")
    public ModelAndView getAccountSummary(
        @PathVariable("comClientId") String commercialClientId) {
        // setup of variable as was removed.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("XmlView", 
            BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "accsumm", as);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

### Controller 2

```
package org.example;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/loccovginquiry.*")
public class LocationCovgController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loccovginquiry.*method={method}")
    public ModelAndView locationCovgInquiryByPolicyNo(
        @PathVariable("method")String method) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("XmlView",
            BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "loccovg", covgs);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

### Servlet Config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example." />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"     p:order="0">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
      <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
    </map>
   </property>

  <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html"/>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
  <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
     <list>
         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
          </bean>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="defaultViews">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
      </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

<bean id="XmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
  <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.example.policy.dto.AccountSummary"/>
  <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.example.policy.dto.InsuredName"/>
  <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.example.policy.dto.Producer"/>
  <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.example.policy.dto.PropertyLocCoverage"/>
  <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.example.policy.dto.PropertyLocCoverages"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

Comment: Moved comment to an answer instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is the annotations at class level, for your case try removing them and just use the annotations at method level. Also if you got the error again, please post the stacktrace.

Also use RequestParam to get param values and PathVariable to access the pathvariables. Simply for the URL `\home\user\{username}\?p=rand`, to get the `username` use pathvariable and use requestparam to get `p`

Comment: After playing with it some more I stopped and started websphere back up and everything started working (as in the code I provided above).  

However, I am very interested in understanding the difference between the PathVariable vs the RequestParam.  I tried substituting RequestParam for my PathVariable and I started to get a 404 error.  Can you shed some light on the difference?

Thanks again for you insight.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable` to bind request parameters (i.e. parameters which come after `?`, you also don't need to include them into `@RequestMapping`). Also, you don't need `@RequestMapping` at class level for this configuration:

### Controller 1

```
package org.example;

@Controller
public class PolicyInquiryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/polinq")
    public ModelAndView getAccountSummary(
        @RequestParam("comClientId") String commercialClientId) {
        // setup of variable as was removed.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("XmlView", 
            BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "accsumm", as);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

### Controller 2

```
package org.example;

@Controller
public class LocationCovgController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loccovginquiry")
    public ModelAndView locationCovgInquiryByPolicyNo(
        @RequestParam("method") String method) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("XmlView",
            BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "loccovg", covgs);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped and started websphere and the code started to work. Previously I had simply "published" the changes to webpshere or "cleaned" the project within RAD (Rational Application Developer) and it appears that neither of those options are completely refreshing the code on the server. Right now the code works 100% of the time.